# Laravel old($field) in select2/select returning wrong value

Tags: string, laravel, select, jquery-select2

The following code returns always the first value as selected, rather than empty!

```
<select class="select2" autocomplete="off" name="{{$field_name}}">
   <option></option>
   @foreach(explode(',', "a,b,c") as $key=> $value)
     <option value='{{$key}}' @if (old($field_name) == $key) selected="selected" @endif>{{$value}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Somehow, the `old($field_name) == $key returns 0` which makes the select statement always puts the first option as the selected, instead of a placeholder for example.

Even when `old($field_name) on its own returning ""`

Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: To split with `,`, you need no regex, use `explode(',', 'a,b,c,d')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh thank you for the neat alternative i revised my code accordingly.

Comment: After submitting the form, does your "field_name" as an actual value in the request ? `request()->input('field_name')` also, what does contain `$field_name` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier yes, there are no issues after, my main issue is when loading, the `(old($field_name)) returns null/empty`, but if you do `old($field_name) == $key`, it `returns 0`!?!

Comment: Because `null == 0` = **true** but `null === 0` = **false**

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier that makes sense, for now a solution that worked for me was to check for null & key so `<option value='{{$key}}' @if(old($field_name) != '' && old($field_name) == $key) selected='selected' @endif>{{$value}}</option>`

Comment: I believe this could work too `old($field_name, 'none') == $key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conclusion of `'' == 0 = true` and `'' === 0 = false`

```
<select class="select2" autocomplete="off" name="{{$field_name}}">
   <option></option>
   @foreach(explode(',', "a,b,c") as $key=> $value)
         <option value='{{$key}}' @if(!is_null(old($field_name)) && old($field_name) == $key) selected='selected' @endif>{{$value}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

will fix the issue